# Extraindo arquivo com ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android

Olá, preciso implementar o `ProgressDialog  enquanto o arquivo está sendo extraído.

Meu código de extração está a seguir. Agora falta apenas implementar o `ProgressDialog`, lembrando que o código abaixado já foi tentado ser implementado o `ProgressDialog` por mim, mas não funcionou, ele recebe a penas o `Toast`:

```
private Button et1;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

...
et1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setMessage("Extraindo arquivo...");
pDialog.setCancelable(false);

et1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v1){
        etap1();    
    }
});

...

public void etap1(){
    showpDialog(); <--

    String zipFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
    .getAbsolutePath()+"/"; 
    unpackZip(zipFilePath, "arquivo.zip"); 
} 

private boolean unpackZip(String path, String zipname) { 
    InputStream is; 
    ZipInputStream zis; 
    try {
        String filename; 
        is = new FileInputStream(path + zipname); 
        zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is)); 
        ZipEntry mZipEntry; byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
        int count; 
        while ((mZipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
            filename = mZipEntry.getName(); 

            if (mZipEntry.isDirectory()) { 
                File fmd = new File(path + filename); 
                fmd.mkdirs(); 
                continue; 
            } 
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + filename); 
            while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) { 
                fout.write(buffer, 0, count); 
            } 
            fout.close(); zis.closeEntry(); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Extraído com sucesso", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }

        hidepDialog(); <--
        zis.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); 
        return false; 
    } 

    hidepDialog(); <--
    return true; 
}

private void showpDialog() { <--
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hidepDialog() { <--
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

O arquivo é extraído sem problemas, não há erros no código de extração, apenas o `ProgressDialog` que não aparece.

Alguem consegue me ajudar a encontrar o erro?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde amigo.

O que pode estar acontecendo é que seu processo de extração do arquivo, rodando na **thread principal (*UI Thread*)**, deve estar prejudicando a atualização da tela, "congelando" a tela, então seu *dialog* não é exibido.

Sugiro que faça a extração numa **thread a parte**, assim você pode deixar a thread principal encarregada de exibir seu *dialog*.

Uma ótima alternativa para trabalhar com threads no Android é a utilização da classe **AsyncTask**.

Toda **lógica de extração** deve ficar numa classe a parte que **estende a classe AsyncTask**.

Nesta classe você pode sobrescrever os seguintes métodos:

- **doInBackground**: aqui vai o código responsável por extrair seu arquivo;
- **onPreExecute**: aqui vai o código que será executado antes do processo de extração começar, por exemplo, exibir o dialog aqui;
- **onPostExecute**: neste método o código para execução após o término do processo, por exemplo, ocultar o dialog;

Mais informações: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Um exemplo pra ajudar a entender melhor:

```
// classe que extrai o arquivo e estente AsyncTask
public class ExtrairTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // variável do dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // construtor padrão
    public ExtrairTask() {

        // instanciando o dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Extraindo arquivo...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
        /*
            aqui vai o código para extrair o  arquivo... 
            ele pode ser implementando aqui ou pode ser feita a chamada de uma função
        */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

// sua activity, onde o usuário executa a ação para extrair o arquivo
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // variável da sua tarefa de extração
   private ExtrairTask et;

   public void extrairArquivo(View v) {

        // em resposta a uma ação do usuário, instanciamos a tarefa e executamos
        et = new ExtrairTask
        et.execute();
   }

}
```

OBS.: o código não foi compilado, pois foi adicionado apenas a título de exemplo para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Olá amigo, exatamente isso. A tela está congelando, da uma travadinha exatamente na hora da extração. Vou buscar mais sobre a classe AsyncTask, muito obrigado!

Comment: Amigo, adicionei um exemplo na resposta para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Amigo, que maravilha ... Muito obrigado, felizão aqui. Mas assim, e se eu quiser executar duas tarefas de uma só vez, tu sabes como faz? Ex: Depois de extrair o arquivo, quero excluí-lo. Fazer ambos de uma só vez, é complicado? Lembrando que já tenho o código de excluir, só não sei como determinar primeiro pra extrair e depois excluir. Muito obrigado mais uma vez, você não sabe o quanto me ajudou.

Comment: Se as duas tarefas podem ser executadas em sequência, você pode colocar tudo dentro de uma mesma thread, chamando o método de extração e na sequência o de exclusão, tudo dentro do **doInBackground**. Agora, se você quiser fazer uma AsyncTask para cada operação deve saber que os procedimentos serão assíncronos, então simplesmente chamando um após o outro (com o método **execute**) na activity principal não garante que serão executados, na prática, um após o outro.