# Erro ao importar arquivos csv do FTP para a aplicação

Tags: java, android, ftp

Estou criando um aplicativo e estou tentando importar uns arquivos csv que estão no ftp para dentro do android.

então tenho a dela da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no Spinner vai listar todos os arquivos presentes na pasta "import" que esta dentro do meu FTP.

porem quando vai realizar esta listagem que ocorre o erro, vamos aos códigos:

classe ImportaFTPActivity:

```
package realsysten.com.br.sigarestaurante;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Vitor on 14/06/2016.
 */
public class importaFtpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spImport;
    ArrayList<String> arquivosFTP = new ArrayList<String>();
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.importa_ftp);

        spImport = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spImport);
        ImportItens();

        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnImpInfos);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(importaFtpActivity.this, "FTP",
                        "Sincrozinzando dados...", false, true);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);

                ChamaImport();
            }
        });

        Button biv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVoltar);
        biv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(importaFtpActivity.this, OpcoesActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void ImportItens() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listarArquivosFTP();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void ChamaImport() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                efetuarDownload();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void listarArquivosFTP() {
        FTPController ftp = new FTPController();
        ftp.conectar("192.168.2.5", "vitor", "248693751qQ", 21);
        ftp.mudarDiretorio("/import");
        FTPFile[] arquivos = ftp.dir("/import");
        if (arquivos != null) {
            int lenght = arquivos.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
                FTPFile f = arquivos[i];
                if (f.isFile()) {
                    arquivosFTP.add(f.getName());

                }
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> arraAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arquivosFTP);
            spImport.setAdapter(arraAdapter);
        }
    }

    public void efetuarDownload() {
        String lstrArq = "";
        try {
            FTPController ftp = new FTPController();
            lstrArq = "/" + spImport.getSelectedItem().toString();
            File lArquivos = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), lstrArq);

            if (!lArquivos.exists()) {
                lArquivos.mkdir();
            }
            ftp.conectar("192.168.2.5", "vitor", "248693751qQ", 21);

            ftp.download("/Import", spImport.getSelectedItem().toString(), lArquivos.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Classe FTPController:

```
package realsysten.com.br.sigarestaurante;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by Vitor on 14/06/2016.
 */
public class FTPController{

    FTPClient mFTP;
    private String TAG = "classeFTP";

    public FTPFile[] dir(String diretorio) {
        try {
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFTP.listFiles(diretorio);
            return ftpFiles;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Erro: não foi possivel listar os arquivos e pastas do diretorio " +
                    diretorio + " . " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean mudarDiretorio(String diretorio) {
        try {
            mFTP.changeWorkingDirectory(diretorio);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Erro: não foi possivel mudar o diretorio para " + diretorio);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean desconecta() {
        try {
            mFTP.disconnect();
            mFTP = null;
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Erro: ao desconectar. " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean conectar(String host, String usuario, String senha, int porta){
        try {
            mFTP = new FTPClient();
            mFTP.connect(host, porta);
            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTP.getReplyCode())) {
                boolean status = mFTP.login(usuario, senha);

                mFTP.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                mFTP.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                return status;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERRO: não foi possivel conectar " + host);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean download(String diretorioOrigem, String arqOrigem, String arqDestino) {
        boolean status = false;

        try {
            mudarDiretorio(diretorioOrigem);
            FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream(arqDestino);
            mFTP.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFTP.enterLocalActiveMode();

            status = mFTP.retrieveFile(arqOrigem, desFileStream);
            desFileStream.close();
            desconecta();
            return status;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Erro: Falha ao efetuar download. " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return status;
    }

    public boolean upload(String diretorio, String nomeArquivo) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            FileInputStream arqEnviar = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + diretorio);
            mFTP.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE);
            mFTP.setFileType(FTPClient.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE);
            mFTP.storeFile(nomeArquivo, arqEnviar);
            desconecta();
            return status;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Erro: falha ao efetuar upload. " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

quando o aplicativo executa o `ImportItens();` que esta no metodo `onCreate`da classe `ImportFTP`, ele faz toda a execução certinho, o `ftp.conectar`, o `ftp.mudarDiretorio`, o `ftp.dir`, mas quando chega no `spImport.setAdapter(arraAdapter);` ocorre o seguinte erro:

erro:

> 06-15 12:19:47.433 31113-31623/realsysten.com.br.sigarestaurante E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-321
>                                                                                          Process: realsysten.com.br.sigarestaurante, PID: 31113
>                                                                                          android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6556)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:3034)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:761)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:761)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:761)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:761)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:761)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:761)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:10555)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.setFocusable(View.java:7481)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:738)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setAdapter(AbsSpinner.java:116)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(Spinner.java:508)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.setAdapter(AppCompatSpinner.java:391)
>                                                                                              at realsysten.com.br.sigarestaurante.importaFtpActivity.listarArquivosFTP(importaFtpActivity.java:97)
>                                                                                              at realsysten.com.br.sigarestaurante.importaFtpActivity$3.run(importaFtpActivity.java:66)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos lá, o que ocorre é que você está tentando atualizar a tela a partir de uma **thread diferente** daquela responsável por gerenciar os componentes (a thread responsável por isso é a ***UIThread***).

O seu método `listarArquivosFTP` tenta atualizar a tela, na linha `spImport.setAdapter(arraAdapter)`, e ele é chamado **dentro de uma nova thread** a partir do `ImportItens`. Por isso você tem essa exceção lançada.

```
public void ImportItens() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listarArquivosFTP();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

.
   .
   .

```
public void listarArquivosFTP() {
    FTPController ftp = new FTPController();
    ftp.conectar("192.168.2.5", "vitor", "248693751qQ", 21);
    ftp.mudarDiretorio("/import");
    FTPFile[] arquivos = ftp.dir("/import");
    if (arquivos != null) {
        int lenght = arquivos.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
            FTPFile f = arquivos[i];
            if (f.isFile()) {
                arquivosFTP.add(f.getName());

            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arraAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arquivosFTP);

        spImport.setAdapter(arraAdapter);

    }
}
```

Existem algumas alternativas para contornar isso, e uma delas é utilizando e método ***runOnUiThread***. Este método vai executar seu conteúdo diretamente na UIThread.

Veja como ficaria seu código:

```
public void listarArquivosFTP() {
    FTPController ftp = new FTPController();
    ftp.conectar("192.168.2.5", "vitor", "248693751qQ", 21);
    ftp.mudarDiretorio("/import");
    FTPFile[] arquivos = ftp.dir("/import");
    if (arquivos != null) {
        int lenght = arquivos.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
            FTPFile f = arquivos[i];
            if (f.isFile()) {
                arquivosFTP.add(f.getName());

            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arraAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arquivosFTP);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               spImport.setAdapter(arraAdapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: deu certo, eu tinha visto mesmo que tinha que usar este `runOnUiThread`  mas tava colocando no lugar errado, estava fazendo como o @Furflez me disse, ai estava dando um erro de `MainNetWork` algo assim, mas desta forma deu certo, apareceu os itens no spinner.

muito obrigado pela sua ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece porque você está tentando alterar seu spinner de dentro da thread no seu método `ImportItens()`, considere utilizar [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) para isso, no método `onPostExecute()` você consegue alterar seu spinner depois da execução do `doInBackground()`.

Mas você pode também alterar o seu método `ImportarItens` para:

```
    public void ImportItens() {

        suaActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   //aqui seu código
                   listarArquivosFTP();     
                }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Isso mesmo Furflez, esta também é uma boa alternativa. Aqui tem um exemplo implementado para nosso amigo consultar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130867/extraindo-arquivo-com-progressdialog/130874#130874

Comment: eu usaria Asynctask, mas, sempre da errado, não consigo fazer funcionar kkkkkk