# Ajuda com AsyncTask e progressbar

Tags: android

Faço conexão com o banco de dados **SQL Server** 9 e consigo conectar ao mesmo.
Eu fiz uma DAO de Conexão e uma tela para receber os valores.

estou com um problema na tela onde recebe os valores, pois criei uma `AsyncTask` para receber os valores mas a mesma fica em loop. no fim do proceso. alguem poderia me ajudar e informar onde estou errando (comecei agora pouco nesta área e estou meio perdido)

Segue abaixo o meu código.

Minha classe de conexão:

**ConexaoDao.java**

```
public class ConexaoDao {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection dbConnect(ObjetoConexao objConexao) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String connectionUrl = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" +
            objConexao.db_connect_string + ";" +
            "databaseName=" + objConexao.db_name + ";user=" +objConexao.db_userid + ";password=" + objConexao.db_password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problemas ao conectar com o banco de dados: " );
        }


        return conn;
    }
}
```

Minha classe de pesquisa:

**Dao__PcPombal.java**

```
public class Dao__PcPombal extends Context{

    public String nomeTabela() {

        String nomeResTorres = "";
        ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
        ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
        objConexao.db_connect_string = "ronaldesantos.hopto.org:1433";
        objConexao.db_name = "Barbacena2";
        objConexao.db_userid = "sa";
        objConexao.db_password = "flextelecom";
        Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);


        if (conn == null){
            nomeResTorres = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";
        } else
            if (conn != null) 
            try {
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                String queryString = "select TOP 1 Area ,Source,Message from Alarmes Where AREA = 'POÇO POMBAL' AND Source ='xo_Alarmes.Falta_Energia' order By E3TimeStamp DESC ";

                ResultSet rs;
                rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);

                if (rs.next()) {
                    nomeResTorres = rs.getString("Message");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                nomeResTorres = e.getMessage();
            }

        return nomeResTorres ;
    }



    public String nomeTabela2() {
        String nomeResTorres2 = "";
        ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
        ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
        objConexao.db_connect_string = "ronaldesantos.hopto.org:1433";
        objConexao.db_name = "Barbacena2";
        objConexao.db_userid = "sa";
        objConexao.db_password = "flextelecom";
        Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);

        if (conn == null){
            nomeResTorres2 = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";
        } else
            if (conn != null) 
                try {
                    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                    String queryString = "select TOP 1 Code from Tbl_Comunicacao_Pc_Pombal where Situacao = 'Recepção (RX) - Aguardando' or Situacao = 'Recepção (RX) - OK' or Situacao = 'Recepção (RX) - Erro' order By E3TimeStamp DESC ";
                    ResultSet rs;

                    rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);


                    if (rs.next()) {
                        nomeResTorres2 = rs.getString("Code");

                        if (nomeResTorres2.equals("255")) {
                            nomeResTorres2 = "Aguardando Recepção";
                        } else if (nomeResTorres2.equals("0")) {
                            nomeResTorres2 = "Recepção OK";
                        } else if (nomeResTorres2.equals("4")) {
                            nomeResTorres2 = "Recepção OK";
                        } else if (nomeResTorres2.equals("1")) {
                            nomeResTorres2 = "Falha na Recepção";
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    nomeResTorres2 = e.getMessage();
                }

        return ""+ nomeResTorres2;
    }


    public String nomeTabela3() {
        String nomeResTorres3 = "";
        ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
        ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
        objConexao.db_connect_string = "ronaldesantos.hopto.org:1433";
        objConexao.db_name = "Barbacena2";
        objConexao.db_userid = "sa";
        objConexao.db_password = "flextelecom";
        Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);




        if (conn == null){

            nomeResTorres3 = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";

        } else
            if (conn != null) 
                try {
                    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                    String queryString = "select TOP 1 Area,Source,Message from Alarmes Where AREA = 'POÇO POMBAL' AND Source ='xo_Alarmes.Presenca' order By E3TimeStamp DESC ";
                    ResultSet rs;

                    rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);



                    if (rs.next()) {

                        nomeResTorres3 = rs.getString("Message");
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    nomeResTorres3 = e.getMessage();
                }

        return ""+ nomeResTorres3;
    }

    public String nomeTabela5() {
        String nomeResTorres5 = "";
        ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
        ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
        objConexao.db_connect_string = "ronaldesantos.hopto.org:1433";
        objConexao.db_name = "Barbacena2";
        objConexao.db_userid = "sa";
        objConexao.db_password = "flextelecom";
        Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);



        if (conn == null){
            nomeResTorres5 = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";
        } else

        if (conn != null) 
            try {
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                String queryString = "select TOP 1 Area ,Source,Message from Alarmes Where AREA = 'POÇO POMBAL' AND Source ='xo_Alarmes.Sobrecarga' order By E3TimeStamp DESC ";
                ResultSet rs;

                rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);


                if (rs.next()) {
                    nomeResTorres5 = rs.getString("Message");
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                nomeResTorres5 = e.getMessage();
            }

        return "" + nomeResTorres5;
    }

    public String nomeTabela6() {
        String nomeResTorres6 = "";
        ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
        ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
        objConexao.db_connect_string = "ronaldesantos.hopto.org:1433";
        objConexao.db_name = "Barbacena2";
        objConexao.db_userid = "sa";
        objConexao.db_password = "flextelecom";
        Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);



        if (conn == null){
            nomeResTorres6 = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";
        } else
            if (conn != null) 
                try {
                    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                    String queryString = "select TOP 1 Estado from Tbl_Acionamentos_Pc_Pombal order By E3TimeStamp DESC ";
                    ResultSet rs;

                    rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);


                    if (rs.next()) {
                        nomeResTorres6 = rs.getString("Estado");
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    nomeResTorres6 = e.getMessage();
                }

        return "" + nomeResTorres6;
    }
}
```

E a parte onde estou usando a `AsyncTask` (caso tenha falha na conexão ele entra nesta tela até me dar um retorno ou se estiver ok ele me da o retorno rápido)

**Act_Poco_Pombal.java**

```
public class Act_Poco_Pombal extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btnFechar;
    private TextView tvNomeComunicacao;
    private ImageView ImgSinal;
    private ImageView ImgStatus;
    private TextView tvNomeStatus;
    private TextView tvNomePresenca;
    private ImageView ImgPresenca;
    private TextView tvNomeFalha;
    private ImageView Imgfalha;
    private TextView tvNomeEnergia;
    private ImageView ImgEnergia;



    String Aguardanando = "Aguardando Recepção";
    String Recepcao = "Recepção OK";
    String Falha = "Falha na Recepção";
    String PresencaAc = "Sensor Invasão Atuado";
    String PresencaN = "Sensor Invasão Desarmado";
    String FalhaAc = "Sobrecarga Motor";
    String FalhaN = "Rearme Sobrecarga";
    String StatusAc = "Ligado";
    String StatusN = "Desligado";
    String EnergiaAc = "Falta Enegia Eletrica";
    String EnergiaN = "Enegia Eletrica Restabelecida"; String FalhaCon = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act__poco__pombal);


        btnFechar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFechar);
        btnFechar.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvNomeComunicacao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeComunicacao);
        ImgSinal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgSinal);
        ImgStatus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgStatus);
        ImgPresenca = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgPresenca);
        tvNomePresenca = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomePresenca);
        Imgfalha = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgFalha);
        tvNomeFalha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeFalha);
        tvNomeStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeEstado);
        ImgEnergia = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgEnergia);
        tvNomeEnergia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeEnergia);
        Processo processo = new Processo(this);
        processo.execute(3000, 2000, 4000);

    }

    public class Processo extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, Integer> {

        private ProgressDialog progress;
        private Context context;

        public Processo(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Cria novo um ProgressDialogo e exibe
            progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progress.setMessage("conecatando-se ao banco de dados");
            progress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... paramss) {
            for (int i = 0; i < paramss.length; i++) {
                try {
                    //Simula processo...
                    Thread.sleep(paramss[i]);

                    //Atualiza a interface através do onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(i + "...");

                    Dao__PcPombal dao__pcPomball= new Dao__PcPombal();
                    Dao__PcPombal dao__pcPombal2= new Dao__PcPombal();
                    Dao__PcPombal dao__pcPombal3= new Dao__PcPombal();
                    Dao__PcPombal dao__pcPombal4= new Dao__PcPombal();
                    Dao__PcPombal dao__pcPombal5= new Dao__PcPombal();

                    String nomeEnergia = dao__pcPomball.nomeTabela();
                    String nomeComunicacao = dao__pcPombal2.nomeTabela2();
                    String nomePresenca = dao__pcPombal3.nomeTabela3();
                    String nomeFalha = dao__pcPombal4.nomeTabela5();
                    String nomeAcionamento = dao__pcPombal5.nomeTabela6();

                    if (nomeComunicacao.equals(Aguardanando)) {
                        tvNomeComunicacao.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFEED04"));
                        tvNomeComunicacao.setText("" + "Aguardando Recepção");
                        ImgSinal.setImageResource(R.drawable.samarelo);
                    } else if (nomeComunicacao.equals(Recepcao)) {
                        tvNomeComunicacao.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomeComunicacao.setText("" + " Recepção OK");
                        ImgSinal.setImageResource(R.drawable.sverde);
                    } else if (nomeComunicacao.equals(Falha)) {
                        tvNomeComunicacao.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                        tvNomeComunicacao.setText("" + "Falha na Recepção");
                        ImgSinal.setImageResource(R.drawable.svermelho);
                    } else if (nomeComunicacao.equals(FalhaCon)){
                        tvNomeComunicacao.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomeComunicacao.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");
                    }

                    if (nomePresenca.equals(PresencaN)) {
                        tvNomePresenca.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomePresenca.setText("" + " Sensor Invasão Desarmado");
                        ImgPresenca.setImageResource(R.drawable.presencaon);
                    } else if (nomePresenca.equals(PresencaAc)) {
                        tvNomePresenca.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                        tvNomePresenca.setText("" + "Sensor Invasão Atuado");
                        ImgPresenca.setImageResource(R.drawable.presenca);
                    } else if (nomePresenca.equals(FalhaCon)) {
                        tvNomePresenca.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomePresenca.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");
                    } else if (nomePresenca.isEmpty()) {
                        tvNomePresenca.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomePresenca.setText("" + " Sensor Invasão Desarmado");
                        ImgPresenca.setImageResource(R.drawable.presencaon);
                    }

                    if (nomeFalha.equals(FalhaN)){
                        tvNomeFalha.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomeFalha.setText("" + " Rearme Falha");
                    } else if (nomeFalha.equals(FalhaAc)) {
                        tvNomeFalha.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                        tvNomeFalha.setText("" + "Falha Motor");
                        Imgfalha.setImageResource(R.drawable.falhaon);
                    }else if (nomeFalha.equals(FalhaCon)){
                        tvNomeFalha.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomeFalha.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");
                    }else if (nomeFalha.isEmpty()){
                        tvNomeFalha.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomeFalha.setText("" + " Rearme Falha");
                    }


                    if (nomeEnergia.equals(EnergiaN)){
                        tvNomeEnergia.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomeEnergia.setText("" + " Enegia Eletrica Ok");
                        ImgEnergia.setImageResource(R.drawable.energiaon);
                    } else if (nomeEnergia.equals(EnergiaAc)) {
                        tvNomeEnergia.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                        tvNomeEnergia.setText("" + "Falta Enegia Eletrica");
                        ImgEnergia.setImageResource(R.drawable.energiaoff);
                    } else if (nomeEnergia.equals(FalhaCon)){
                        tvNomeEnergia.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomeEnergia.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");
                    } else if (nomeEnergia.isEmpty()){
                        tvNomeEnergia.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomeEnergia.setText("" + " Enegia Eletrica OK");
                        ImgEnergia.setImageResource(R.drawable.energiaon);
                    }


                    if (nomeAcionamento.equals(StatusN)){
                        tvNomeStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                        tvNomeStatus.setText("" + " Poço Desligado");
                        ImgStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.pocooff);
                    } else if (nomeAcionamento.equals(StatusAc)) {
                        tvNomeStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomeStatus.setText("" + "Poço Ligado");
                        ImgStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.pocon);
                    } else if (nomeAcionamento.equals(FalhaCon)){
                        tvNomeStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                        tvNomeStatus.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");
                    } else if (nomeAcionamento.isEmpty()){
                        tvNomeStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                        tvNomeStatus.setText("" + " Poço Desligado");
                        ImgStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.pocooff);
                    }




                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            //Cancela progressDialogo
            progress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            //Atualiza mensagem
            progress.setMessage(values[0]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
        finish();
    }

}
```

Lucas, fiz como você falou, só que ao iniciaro processo ele para nos 25% e quando, eu clico na tela ele me retorna um erro, " Barbacena isn't respondig. do you whant to close it? - lembrando que tirei o while  porque ficava em loop mesmo com o fim do processo

public class Act_Poco_Pombal extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btnFechar;
    private TextView tvNomeComunicacao;
    private ImageView ImgSinal;
    private ImageView ImgStatus;
    private TextView tvNomeStatus;
    private TextView tvNomePresenca;
    private ImageView ImgPresenca;
    private TextView tvNomeFalha;
    private ImageView Imgfalha;
    private TextView tvNomeEnergia;
    private ImageView ImgEnergia;

```
String Aguardanando = "Aguardando Recepção";
String Recepcao = "Recepção OK";
String Falha = "Falha na Recepção";
String PresencaAc = "Sensor Invasão Atuado";
String PresencaN = "Sensor Invasão Desarmado";
String FalhaAc = "Sobrecarga Motor";
String FalhaN = "Rearme Sobrecarga";
String StatusAc = "Ligado";
String StatusN = "Desligado";
String EnergiaAc = "Falta Enegia Eletrica";
String EnergiaN = "Enegia Eletrica Restabelecida";                                                                                                                                              String FalhaCon = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";



    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act__poco__pombal);


    btnFechar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFechar);
    btnFechar.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvNomeComunicacao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeComunicacao);
    ImgSinal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgSinal);
    ImgStatus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgStatus);
    ImgPresenca = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgPresenca);
    tvNomePresenca = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomePresenca);
    Imgfalha = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgFalha);
    tvNomeFalha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeFalha);
    tvNomeStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeEstado);
    ImgEnergia = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgEnergia);
    tvNomeEnergia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeEnergia);
    ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    TextView texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);

    new MinhaTask(this, progress, texto).execute();

}


    public class MinhaTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, String> {

       private ProgressBar progressBar;
       private TextView texto;
        private int total = 0;
        private int PROGRESSO = 25;


        public MinhaTask(Context context, ProgressBar progressBar, TextView texto) {

            this.progressBar = progressBar;
            this.texto = texto;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
           texto.setText("0%");
            super.onPreExecute();

            tvNomeComunicacao.setText("Conectando-se ao banco de dados");
            tvNomeEnergia.setText("Conectando-se ao banco de dados");
            tvNomeFalha.setText("Conectando-se ao banco de dados");
            tvNomePresenca.setText("Conectando-se ao banco de dados");
            tvNomeStatus.setText("Conectando-se ao banco de dados");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {


                try {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);




                    for (int i = 0; i <= params.length; i++) {
                            publishProgress();
                            Thread.sleep(1000);



                            }


                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {



                total += PROGRESSO;
                progressBar.incrementProgressBy(PROGRESSO);
                texto.setText(total + "%");




            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {




            Dao__PcPombal dao__pcPomball = new Dao__PcPombal();
            Dao__PcPombal dao__pcPombal2 = new Dao__PcPombal();
            Dao__PcPombal dao__pcPombal3 = new Dao__PcPombal();
            Dao__PcPombal dao__pcPombal4 = new Dao__PcPombal();
            Dao__PcPombal dao__pcPombal5 = new Dao__PcPombal();

            String nomeEnergia = dao__pcPomball.nomeTabela();
            String nomeComunicacao = dao__pcPombal2.nomeTabela2();
            String nomePresenca = dao__pcPombal3.nomeTabela3();
            String nomeFalha = dao__pcPombal4.nomeTabela5();
            String nomeAcionamento = dao__pcPombal5.nomeTabela6();

            if (nomeComunicacao.equals(Aguardanando)) {

                tvNomeComunicacao.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFEED04"));
                tvNomeComunicacao.setText("" + "Aguardando Recepção");
                ImgSinal.setImageResource(R.drawable.samarelo);


            } else if (nomeComunicacao.equals(Recepcao)) {

                tvNomeComunicacao.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                tvNomeComunicacao.setText("" + " Recepção OK");
                ImgSinal.setImageResource(R.drawable.sverde);

            } else if (nomeComunicacao.equals(Falha)) {

                tvNomeComunicacao.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                tvNomeComunicacao.setText("" + "Falha na Recepção");
                ImgSinal.setImageResource(R.drawable.svermelho);


            } else if (nomeComunicacao.equals(FalhaCon)) {

                tvNomeComunicacao.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                tvNomeComunicacao.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");


            }

            if (nomePresenca.equals(PresencaN)) {

                tvNomePresenca.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                tvNomePresenca.setText("" + " Sensor Invasão Desarmado");
                ImgPresenca.setImageResource(R.drawable.presencaon);

            } else if (nomePresenca.equals(PresencaAc)) {

                tvNomePresenca.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                tvNomePresenca.setText("" + "Sensor Invasão Atuado");
                ImgPresenca.setImageResource(R.drawable.presenca);


            } else if (nomePresenca.equals(FalhaCon)) {

                tvNomePresenca.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                tvNomePresenca.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");

            } else if (nomePresenca.isEmpty()) {

                tvNomePresenca.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                tvNomePresenca.setText("" + " Sensor Invasão Desarmado");
                ImgPresenca.setImageResource(R.drawable.presencaon);

            }

            if (nomeFalha.equals(FalhaN)) {

                tvNomeFalha.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                tvNomeFalha.setText("" + " Rearme Falha");

            } else if (nomeFalha.equals(FalhaAc)) {

                tvNomeFalha.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                tvNomeFalha.setText("" + "Falha Motor");
                Imgfalha.setImageResource(R.drawable.falhaon);


            } else if (nomeFalha.equals(FalhaCon)) {

                tvNomeFalha.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                tvNomeFalha.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");


            } else if (nomeFalha.isEmpty()) {

                tvNomeFalha.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                tvNomeFalha.setText("" + " Rearme Falha");
            }


            if (nomeEnergia.equals(EnergiaN)) {

                tvNomeEnergia.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                tvNomeEnergia.setText("" + " Enegia Eletrica Ok");
                ImgEnergia.setImageResource(R.drawable.energiaon);

            } else if (nomeEnergia.equals(EnergiaAc)) {

                tvNomeEnergia.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                tvNomeEnergia.setText("" + "Falta Enegia Eletrica");
                ImgEnergia.setImageResource(R.drawable.energiaoff);

            } else if (nomeEnergia.equals(FalhaCon)) {

                tvNomeEnergia.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                tvNomeEnergia.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");

            } else if (nomeEnergia.isEmpty()) {

                tvNomeEnergia.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                tvNomeEnergia.setText("" + " Enegia Eletrica OK");
                ImgEnergia.setImageResource(R.drawable.energiaon);
            }


            if (nomeAcionamento.equals(StatusN)) {

                tvNomeStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                tvNomeStatus.setText("" + " Poço Desligado");
                ImgStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.pocooff);

            } else if (nomeAcionamento.equals(StatusAc)) {

                tvNomeStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                tvNomeStatus.setText("" + "Poço Ligado");
                ImgStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.pocon);


            } else if (nomeAcionamento.equals(FalhaCon)) {

                tvNomeStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                tvNomeStatus.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");

            } else if (nomeAcionamento.isEmpty()) {

                tvNomeStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
                tvNomeStatus.setText("" + " Poço Desligado");
                ImgStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.pocooff);



            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
           texto.setText("Tarefa concluída");
            texto.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

    }
```

olha o erro [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo, veja se esta questão te ajuda em alguma coisa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130867/extraindo-arquivo-com-progressdialog

Comment: Em caso de erro ela entra em um Loop nesse for ? Que tipo de erro isso acontece

Comment: Tenta colocar toda a sua lógica do `doInBackground` dentro desse while: `while(!isCancelled())`

Comment: Lucas Bom Dia, eu coloco este While dentro do próprio doInBackground?  depois do loops ele da um erro e fecha a tela

Comment: isso, quando um erro ocorre, normalmente a Async é cancelada. Então seria algo do tipo `protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... paramss) { while(!isCancelled()){
            for (int i = 0; i < paramss.length; i++) { //sua lógica}}`

Comment: Se possível edite com o erro que ocorre

Comment: Lucas, Boa noite, fiz uma edição lá

Comment: @RonaldoSantos Por favor, não use capturas de tela para exibir o erro. Copie e cole como texto para ajudar os próximos que terão o mesmo problema a encontrar essa pergunta e permitir a compreensão por usuários de leitores de tela.

Answer (score 0):

Vendo seu erro agora ficou fácil identificar, `Only the original Thread that create a view can touch it's views`

Isso acontece porque a AsyncTask roda fora do UI Thread, ou seja, tudo que acontece nela não pode afetar a thread que fica visível ao usuário.

No seu código você altera cores, texto, etc.. de Views que estão na Thread de UI e isso gera essa exceção, de um thread "invadindo" o espaço da outra.

Quando se usa AsyncTask toda e qualquer interação com o usuário deve ser feita nos métodos `onPreExecute` e `onPostExecute`.

Existe como usar o `runOnUiThread` e forçar essa interação, porém, pode causar outros problemas e foge um pouquinho do propósito de usar AsyncTask.

Minha sugestão então é ao invés de fazer as comparações no `doInBackground` , retorne as 4 variáveis que você usa nas comparações e trate isso no `onPostExecute`.

Então os passos são :

1. Alterar o tipo do retorno do método `doInBackground` para `String[]`.
2. Alterar nos parâmetros da classe Processo de `Integer` para `String[]`
3. Colocar as suas variáveis em uma String[]
4. Alterar o tipo de dado do `onPostExecute` para String[]
5. Receber essas variáveis no `onPostExecute`,fazer as comparações e fazer as mudanças na UI

(Nota: Ao trocar o tipo de retorno do `doInBackground` a IDE já vai acusar onde o tipo não está certo, isso pode te ajudar a deixar os 3 pontos com o retorno certo.)

Comment: Bom Dia   .  Fiz Conforme sua sugestão ( está no editado).  só que ao inicar o processo ele fica em 25%  mas o processo está sendo realizado. e outra coisa ao clicar na tela, da um erro e fecha tela . barbacena isn't  responding. do you whant to close it?

Comment: @RonaldoSantos Isso provavelmente esta acontecendo por causa do Thread.Sleep, você trava o processo e o sistema entende que está travado. Quanto ao toque, talvez seja pelo mesmo motivo, porém, ao tocar ele cancelará o processo, neste caso o ideal é tratar o `onCancelled ` ou colocar as opções de não cancelar no progress dialog